# 'Use Credential File' in oracle data integrator in data server what is it used for?

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I want to explore Oracle data integrator , i am not able to understand what does 'Use credential File' option in Data server does in Oracle data integrator. If anyone can explain it would be helpful and i want to improve performance of my oracle data integrator[image] script as well, any ideas on that as well.

Comment: Hi, could you please indicate the exact place where you found that option?

Comment: Hi, i have found that option in the data server topology in physical schema, i want to know what can that be used for?

Comment: Arif, please tell me also the technology.

Comment: I am using Oracle technology in the data server, in physical schema when i check that 'Use Credential File' option it further comes with two boxes Credential file & connection details, can you please explain me in detail what it is used for?

Comment: I don't find those options ..that's why I asked you for more details. could you edit your post and put a screen shot of ODI pointing those options?

Comment: Hi i have added the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I think that I understood. You run ODI in Cloud.
You will need a credential File in order to connect to your database.
The way you obtain that credential file, is:
Credential files are downloaded from the ADW console to the ODI host in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI).

Note: When ODI is deployed from the Marketplace, client credential folders are downloaded from autonomous databases that exist in the OCI compartment containing ODI.

If ADW is in a different compartment than ODI follow the steps below.

> Download the Credentials
>
> Connect to the ODI host using VNC. Refer to the Deployment blog above
>   for details.
>
> Launch Firefox from the Applications>Favorites list.
>
> Follow the steps in Downloading Autonomous Data Warehouse Credentials
>   to obtain the client credentials compressed folder containing the
>   wallet and network configuration files used by ODI to make the
>   connections.

The entire way of connecting is described [here](https://www.ateam-oracle.com/connecting-oracle-data-integrator-marketplace-studio-to-autonomous-databases).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, can you help me out by suggesting different ways by which i can improve the performance, i have tried load balancing, used array fetch size and bacth update size as well, any other method which i can implement as in the source there is huge amount of data.

Comment: I'm happy that everything is clear, now. I could try to help you but, you need to elaborate your problem. Give some examples of bad performance/good performance, where you have problems with performance (tool). Please create a new topic about this. There is a big community that could help you.